# Server.py with Auth0's "Quick Start" Doesn't Work - Flask/Python

Tags: flask, auth0, okta

I get an error when setting up my Auth0 with my Flask server. When running the server, I get "Internal Server Error, The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." I can't seem to find the error as I just followed Auth0's setup protocol. My home.html file is in templates/home.html.

Here is server.py:

```
import json
from os import environ as env
from urllib.parse import quote_plus, urlencode

from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, session, url_for

ENV_FILE = find_dotenv()
if ENV_FILE:
    load_dotenv(ENV_FILE)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = env.get("APP_SECRET_KEY")


oauth = OAuth(app)

oauth.register(
    "auth0",
    client_id=env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret=env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    client_kwargs={
        "scope": "openid profile email",
    },
    server_metadata_url=f'https://{env.get("AUTH0_DOMAIN")}/.well-known/openid-configuration',
)


# Controllers API
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template(
        "home.html",
        session=session.get("user"),
        pretty=json.dumps(session.get("user"), indent=4),
    )


@app.route("/callback", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def callback():
    token = oauth.auth0.authorize_access_token()
    session["user"] = token
    return redirect("/")


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return oauth.auth0.authorize_redirect(
        redirect_uri=url_for("callback", _external=True)
    )


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(
        "https://"
        + env.get("AUTH0_DOMAIN")
        + "/v2/logout?"
        + urlencode(
            {
                "returnTo": url_for("home", _external=True),
                "client_id": env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
            },
            quote_via=quote_plus,
        )
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=env.get("PORT", 3000))
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\Documents\GitHub\Capius\server.py", line 33, in home
    return render_template(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 150, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 64, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jul/2023 19:45:06] "[35m[1mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
[2023-07-09 19:45:07,678] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\Documents\GitHub\Capius\server.py", line 33, in home
    return render_template(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 150, in render_template
    template = app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 126, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 64, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Shashwat Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html
```

I expected the home.html to run after running my flask server. Instead, I get the errors described above. I am not too sure what's wrong, as I followed Auth0's protocol. Home.html is in templates/home.html.

Comment: On the surface, `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html` is saying this is a template (or template location) issue. A way to debug this is to comment out all of the authlib parts, and see if the problem persists.